# Flask-Bokeh-Gunicorn: Models must be owned by a single document

Tags: python, flask, bokeh, gunicorn

Here is a code to run a Flask app along with Bokeh server inspired from
[flask_gunicorn_embed.py on Github](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/examples/howto/server_embed/flask_gunicorn_embed.py).
At first it works like a charm; however, having refreshed the page, this error occurs.

> Models must be owned by only a single document: ... (rest truncated)

By the way, the code gets runned using `gunicorn`.
Also, `create_figure()` function returns a `layout`

```
from Decision_Tree.Plot.decision_tree import create_figure
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    sys.exit()

app = Flask(__name__)


def modify_doc(doc):
    # Create the plot
    plot = create_figure()
    # Embed plot into HTML via Flask Render
    doc.add_root(plot)

bkapp = Application(FunctionHandler(modify_doc))

# This is so that if this app is run using something like "gunicorn -w 4" then
# each process will listen on its own port
sockets, port = bind_sockets("x.x.x.x", 0)


@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def bkapp_page():
    script = server_document('http://x.x.x.x:%d/bkapp' % port)
    return render_template("index.html", script=script, template="Flask")


def bk_worker():
    asyncio.set_event_loop(asyncio.new_event_loop())

    bokeh_tornado = BokehTornado({'/bkapp': bkapp}, extra_websocket_origins=["x.x.x.x:5000"])
    bokeh_http = HTTPServer(bokeh_tornado)
    bokeh_http.add_sockets(sockets)

    server = BaseServer(IOLoop.current(), bokeh_tornado, bokeh_http)
    server.start()
    server.io_loop.start()


from threading import Thread
Thread(target=bk_worker).start()
```

Looking forward to any help!
P.S. Domain replaced with x.x.x.x intentionally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have not included all the code, so it is impossible to say for certain, but the most likely explanation is that you are creating Bokeh models somewhere and re-using them between different calls to `modify_doc`. For example this would be the case, if your `create_figure` function referred to a global `ColumnDataSource` (or whatever) that was created outside the function as a module global. This will not work, Bokeh models cannot be re-used between different docs/sessions. Every call to `modify_doc` needs to return an *entirely new* set of Bokeh models for the session, otherwise different users would have shared state which is not good for many reasons (so it is explicitly disallowed by raising that exception).

Comment: As I reviewed the code again I observed that the global variables (models) have been used. They probably create the problem.

Comment: Would the problem be fixed, if I moved this part to the file that contains those global variables?

Comment: I don't really understand the question, so I will just reiterate: everything returned by `modify_doc` must be a brand-new Bokeh model, and must not contain anything ever returned by a previous call.